# can't call a class into a GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, class, gesturedetector

I have a GestureDetector that it's child is a row.
on GestureDetector 'ontap' I want to call a class named MyApp that prints entry value but it's not working on GestureDetector's 'ontap'.
calling class works well outside the GestureDetector.
what can I do for it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8276.png)

Comment: Please post the code here and the code of the MyApp class as well,and any error you are having.

Comment: What exactly are your trying to achieve there? Considering MyApp class is a Widget, it's pointless to return it as an onTap callback

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code into void function and the call it from there on tap. it may solve your problem. If you're trying directly to call class from there it will definitely show error or null.